# Short int, Hexa Decimal and Binary bases in C

Tags: c, binary, hex

I'd like your help with analyzing the output of the following code:

```
int f(unsigned short x){
    int count;      
    for (count=0; x!=0; x>>=1){
        if (x & 1)
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int main(void){
    unsigned short x = 0x00ef;

    while (x){
        printf("%d", f(f(x)));
        x<<=4;
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I treat `x` as 239 or **11101111** in binary base.

so  **11101111 != 0** so we enter the while loop: f(f(**11101111**)), then f's count reaches to 7: **11101111** to **01110111** to **00111011**to **00011101** to **00001110** and so on. we have 7 cases where (x&1!=0) then **00000111** is sent to f, and count is 3, 3 is being printed and the original number becomes **11110000** and sent to f, 4 is sent then to f, but then since 4 is **00000100** count=1 and then I expected 1 to be printed, but the output is 3331.

Can someone please point out my mistakes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be expecting the original number to be limited at 8 bits, which is rarely the size of `unsigned short`.

After the first shift, `x` will hold `0x00ef << 4`, i.e. `0x0ef0` which still has the same number of bits set.